# Delegate method not called in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` which is created:

```
class EmployeesSplitViewController: UISplitViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let nav1 = UINavigationController()
    let nav2 = UINavigationController()

    let masterViewController = EmployeesList()
    let detailViewController = EmployeeDetailsTableViewController()
    nav1.viewControllers = [detailViewController]
    nav2.viewControllers = [masterViewController]
    detailViewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.viewControllers = [nav2, nav1]
    self.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = self.view.frame.width / 3
    self.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
 }

}
```

in `EmployeeDetailsTableViewController` I have a custom alert view which add a new employee in coreData and then I would like to call `reloadData` in `EmployeesList`. I use the delagation pattern:

```
protocol EmployeeDetailsTableViewControllerDelegate {
func refreshTable()
}
```

then in `EmployeeDetailsTableViewController`

```
var delegate:EmployeeDetailsTableViewControllerDelegate?


func addButtonTapped(name: String, lastName: String, jobTitle: String) {

    let coreManager =  CoreDataManager()
    coreManager.addNewEmployee(name: name, lastName: lastName, jobTitle: jobTitle)
    alertView.removeFromSuperview()
    blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
    delegate?.refreshTable() //this is the delegate method
}
```

in `EmployeesList`

```
class EmployeesList: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, EmployeeDetailsTableViewControllerDelegate {

   let employeeDetailsVC = EmployeeDetailsTableViewController()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      employeeDetailsVC.delegate = self
   }

   func refreshTable() {
    print("RELOADING") //this never get called
    self.tableView.reloadData()
   }

}
```

`refreshTable` never gets called. What am I missing?

UPDATE: As correctly pointed out by Phillip Mills I was assigning the delegate to the wrong object.  I managed to call the delegate function setting the delegate on `masterViewController`. The only problem now is that I need `masterViewController` also to call masterViewController.tableView.reloadData(). If I move it outside `viewDidLoad` I get the following error: `'NSGenericException', reason: 'The content view controller argument must be the root of its associated view controller hierarchy.'`

```
class EmployeesSplitViewController: UISplitViewController, EmployeeDetailsTableViewControllerDelegate {

    var masterViewController:EmployeesList!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let nav1 = UINavigationController()
        let nav2 = UINavigationController()

        masterViewController = EmployeesList()
        let detailViewController = EmployeeDetailsTableViewController()
        detailViewController.delegate = self
        nav1.viewControllers = [detailViewController]
        nav2.viewControllers = [masterViewController]
        detailViewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.viewControllers = [nav2, nav1]
        self.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = self.view.frame.width / 3
        self.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
    }

    func refreshTable() {
        masterViewController.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines...

```
let detailViewController = EmployeeDetailsTableViewController()
```

...and...

```
let employeeDetailsVC = EmployeeDetailsTableViewController()
```

...each create an object.
That is, each creates a different object.

The one you point to as `detailViewController` gets used to display things on the screen, but it's the other one that is assigned the delegate.

Instead of creating a second controller in `EmployeesList`, set `masterViewController` as the delegate of the **original** `EmployeeDetailsTableViewController` object.

Comment: thanks. This makes sense. I thought that was the problem. How can I do it? in `EmployeesSplitViewController`?

Comment: That seems reasonable.  `detailViewController.delegate = masterViewController`, I assume.

Comment: It seems as if your code for setting up master/detail controllers in the wrong place.  The kind of work you're doing in `viewDidLoad` is normally done in the AppDelegate.  Try doing all your controller set up before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ` completes.